# bar plot width and orders when on top of other bars

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)


x = c("Band 1", "Band 2", "Band 3")
y1 = c("1","2","3")
y2 = c("2","3","4")

to_plot <- data.frame(x=x,y1=y1,y2=y2)
melted<-melt(to_plot, id="x")

ggplot(melted,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity",position = "identity", alpha=.3 ,width = .3)
```

Is it possible to:

(1)  make the width of variable = y1 be .3 and the variable = y2 be .5

(2)  make variable = y1 always be the top bar

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `position_dodge(width=0)` to obtain a completely overlap (throws a warning). For the widths you can create a new variable for each `y*`.

**yields:**

```
melted$width <- with(melted, ifelse(variable=="y1", .3, .5))

ggplot(melted, aes(x=x, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity",
           position = position_dodge(width=0), 
           width = melted$width, alpha=.7)
```

[image]

*Note:* I've changed the `alpha` to .7 to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks Jay. Is there a way to make the y axis start at .1 instead of zero?

Comment: `+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(.1, 1:4), expand = c(.02, .02))`?

Comment: do `melted$value <- as.numeric(melted$value)` first.